# Recovering Wifi Password without Root on Galaxy Note 3

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, password, samsung-galaxy-note-3, wpa-supplicant

I am trying to recover WiFi password without rooting my phone. There are 2 ways I found online. One using a file explorer and the next is using ADB. I tried using ADB but I failed in doing so. I'm really not sure if I did it right but then I just followed the instructions here from [Quora](http://www.quora.com/How-do-you-see-a-saved-Wi-Fi-password-on-Android-without-root-privileges). Anyway, I have pulled the `wpa_supplicant.conf` and this is the only thing I see:

```
update_config=1
eapol_version=1
ap_scan=1
fast_reauth=1
```

I should be seeing this instead of the one above:

```
network={
ssid="NETWORK_NAME_HERE"
psk="PASSWORD_HERE"
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
priority=1
}
```

Is there something that I missed or it's just not really applicable? I have Samsung Galaxy Note 3 SM-N9005.

Comment: Just want to confirm, are you also using Cyanogenmod ROM? The fact that you could pull the file using ADB shown that you have root access (which probably was provided by CM), since normally you can't get system file without root.

Comment: I was wondering exactly the same: trying to pull that file without root gives you a "permission denied". So as that proves you've got root, you could also try apps for [WiFi Password Recovery](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_config#group_423). Apart from that: Yes, you should see the second part (network block) as well – unless the device had never connected to any network, that is.

Comment: @AndrewT. No I'm not using cyanogenmod rom and I did not root my phone.  :)

Comment: @Izzy well some say that we can use pull and push without rooting a device. Well I have tried that app but it just scans for wifi. I have been using my phone since 2013 and I'm pretty sure it's not like that. I'm just wondering why there is no network block in my .conf file....

Comment: Of course you can pull and push without root – but not everything (some files and directories are protected). And I agree, with that block missing in the file, the recovery app probably won't find it either.

Comment: So there's nothing I can do to see the network block without rooting my phone? :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are still connected with wifi than you can recover wifi password by going to your local host in the browser like 192.168.1.1 and than in the password section tick on show password or just click in password field your password will than be revealed to you hope it helps .